# Firestore security rules get(). exists()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have documents in Firestore like the following:

```
BID: "123"
From: "xxx"
Opn: true
```

I need to check if there are another document have `BID == "123"` and `Opn == true` before create the document, because it's not possible to have one more document where Opn is true with same BID.

I try to use `get()` and `exists` but it's not working with 2 data fields.

What I tried:

```
function checkIfThereOpenRoomForSameBBB(xxx) { 
  return !(
    (get(/databases/$(database)/ChatRooms/$(ChatRoom)).data.BID == xxx) &&
    (get(/databases/$(database)/ChatRooms/$(ChatRoom)).data.Opn == true)
  ); 
}
```

is there any solution for this case?

Comment: I Used something like that:

Comment: function checkIfThereOpenRoomForSameBBB(xxx) {
      return !((get(/databases/$(database)/ChatRooms/$(ChatRoom)).data.BID == xxx) && (get(/databases/$(database)/ChatRooms/$(ChatRoom)).data.Opn == true));
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules can't search for data in the database, as that would be prohibitively slow and expensive. All they can do is check if a document exists at a specific path, or read a document as a specific path and check its contents.

This means that any time you want to check if something exists, you'll need to ensure that lives at a known path. So if the combination of `BID` and `Opn=tru` must be unique, you should create a collection where the key of each document consists of the `BID` value and `Opn=true`.

If this is a global requirement for your app, you could even use this key in your existing collection instead of the (likely auto-generated) key you currently use.

Also see:

- [Prevent duplicate entries in Firestore rules not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236388/prevent-duplicate-entries-in-firestore-rules-not-working/54238476#54238476)
- [firebase rule for unique property in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363730/firebase-rule-for-unique-property-in-firestore)
- [I want to write a rule that will don't allow add same document second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865407/i-want-to-write-a-rule-that-will-dont-allow-add-same-document-second-time/56911365#56911365)